# Postgres convert PATH type to ARRAY

Tags: sql, postgresql, path

Is there any way to convert Postgres PATH type to an ARRAY in order to have index access to it's points?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with PostgreSQL alone - you'd have to write your own C function.

With the PostGIS extension, you can cast the `path` to `geometry` and perform the operation there:

```
SELECT array_agg(CAST(geom AS point))
FROM st_dumppoints(CAST(some_path AS geometry));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a variant of this..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION YADAMU.YADAMU_make_closed(point[])
returns point[]
STABLE RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
as
$$
select case 
  when $1[1]::varchar = $1[array_length($1,1)]::varchar then
    $1
  else 
    array_append($1,$1[1])
  end
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
--
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION YADAMU.YADAMU_AsPointArray(path)
returns point[]
STABLE RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
as
$$
--
-- Array of Points from Path
--
select case 
         when isClosed($1) then
           YADAMU.YADAMU_make_closed(array_agg(point(v)))
         else 
           array_agg(point(v))
         end 
        from unnest(string_to_array(left(right($1::VARCHAR,-2),-2),'),(')) v
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
--
```

Eg

```
yadamu=# select * from unnest(YADAMU.YADAMU_asPointArray(Path '((0,1),(1,0),(4,0))'));
 unnest
--------
 (0,1)
 (1,0)
 (4,0)
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `st_dumppoints` and `array_agg`.

To get an array of points that becomes a list of points in Python:

```
select o.osm_ID, array_agg(point(o.way)) as points
from (  select osm_ID, (st_dumppoints( way )).geom way 
        from planet_osm_line ) o
group by o.osm_ID;
```

Returns:

```
-14908307   {(4462712.614234681,-1275901.9494768495), ...}
-14908306   {(4467217.391200562,-1289376.0756383499), ...}
...
```

It's also possible to have each point as an array which is returned as a list of lists in Python:

```
select o.osm_ID, array_agg(array[ST_X(o.way), ST_y(o.way)]) as points
from (  select osm_ID, (st_dumppoints( way )).geom way 
        from planet_osm_line ) o
group by o.osm_ID;
```

Returns:

```
-14908307   {{4462712.614234681,-1275901.9494768495}, ...}
-14908306   {{4467217.391200562,-1289376.0756383499}, ...}
...
```