# Postgresql: access individual points in path?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I've been trying to figure out how to access the individual points of a path (or any other geometric type). I read both chapters 8.8 and 9.11 of the v13 docs, and although this seems (to me) like a very basic requirement, I couldn't find a way to do it. I'm now considering casting the path to a different type like text and extracting the information with string manipulation functions.

Am I missing something here? I also searched SO and it's never been asked, so it's really making me wonder if I'm thinking this in the wrong way.

I would expect some function or operator where I can input a path and an index and get out the corresponding point.

Thanks for any help on this.

PS: I'm using vanilla PostgreSQL 13 (i.e. no postgis). I'm not familiar with postgis, and my initial impression is that it would be overkill for this requirement only (maybe in performance but mostly because I would need to learn about it).

Best regards

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389921/postgres-convert-path-type-to-array - you will need to work with PostGIS.

Comment: Hi @PhilippJohannis, thanks for the quick reply. Is this crazy or what? What good are all the geometry types if I can't ultimately extract the points to do whatever I need, like drawing an svg or similar

Answer (score 0):

same here, dont want gis, as it is too much.

I'd say parse the path::text expression with regular expressions and return an array with points back.

I'll have a go and report back any results.
This function will convert a path to an array of strings. These strings can be converted to points if you want.

```
 create or replace function path2points( path ) returns point[] as
 $$
   with points as (
     select point( unnest(
              string_to_array( regexp_replace( $1::text,'[()][()]','', 'g' ),'),(')
            ) ) as point
   ) select array_agg( point ) from points
 $$ language sql immutable strict;
```

It's quite a silly way to solve this and probably not very fast, but it will do the trick.